# If you're mapping a function over a list in rackect how can you get a reference to the next element?

Tags: list, dictionary, lambda, scheme, racket

If I have a list and I map a lambda function over it how can I get a reference to the next or previous item while processing the current one?

```
(map (lambda (x) x) '(1 2 3))
```

How would I reference the previous or  next element while processing x?

Comment: You can't. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Looks like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Maybe if you explained what you intend to do in the first place... please post a sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

John McCarthy originally made `maplist` and it's defined in `CL` still and predates `map(car)`. It's definition in Scheme would be something like:

```
(define (maplist fun lst)
  (if (null? lst)
      '()
      (cons (fun lst) (maplist fun (cdr lst)))))

(maplist values '(1 2 3 4)) ; ==> ((1 2 3 4) (2 3 4) (3 4) (4))
```

It's slightly more difficult to get each element like `map` but if you need more than the first then it's perfect.

Comment: I like this even more than my answer. It's elegant. Plus if you add an `each` argument, and replace `(fun lst)` with `(fun (each lst))`, you can build some other interesting mapping functions.

Answer (score 3):

Start with your one list, construct two other lists, one 'shifted' right, and the other 'shifted' left.  Like this:

```
(define (process func x)
  (let ((to-front (cons 'front (reverse (cdr (reverse x)))))
        (to-rear  (append (cdr x) (list 'rear))))
    (map func to-front x to-rear)))
```

Note that the stuff above with `reverse` is because `map` expects all lists to have the same length.  So when adding to the front, you need to remove one from the tail.

Also, the provided `func` needs to accept three arguments.

```
> (process list '(a b c))
((front a b) (a b c) (b c rear))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can always use `map` on two `zip`ped lists, i.e.

```
(import (srfi srfi-1)) ; or use some zip implementation
(define a '(1 2 3 4 5))
(map (lambda (x) x)
  (zip a
       (append (cdr a) (list (car a)))))
```

which results in `((1 2) (2 3) (3 4) (4 5) (5 1))`.

Of course, the above assumes "periodic" boundary conditions for the lists (you should modify the boundary conditions for your case).
And also you would need to modify the `lambda` to handle pairs of elements.

Answer (score 2):

For simplicity let's take the case of two elements at a time -- the current and next one. So if you have `(list 1 2 3)`, and a function that takes `this` and `next` args, you want it to be called with:

```
1 2
2 3
3 <some value, let's say 3>
```

You could write that concisely as:

```
(map f xs (append (drop xs 1) (list (last xs))))
```

However the `drop` and `append`-ing means that's not the fastest way to do it.  Instead you could write a `map-slide-pairs` function to do it more directly:

```
#lang racket/base
(require racket/match)

;; map a list as "sliding pairs". For example:
;; (map-slide-pairs cons '(1 2 3)) ==> '((1 . 2)
;;                                       (2 . 3)
;;                                       (3 . 3))
(define (map-slide-pairs f xs #:last-val [last-val #f])
  ;; Concise implementation:
  ;;   (map f xs (append (drop xs 1) (list (last xs)))))
  ;; Faster implementation:
  (let loop ([xs xs])
    (match xs
      [(list) (list)]
      [(list this) (list (f this (or last-val this)))]
      [(list this next more ...) (cons (f this next)
                                       (loop (cons next more)))])))

(module+ test
  (require rackunit)
  (check-equal? (map-slide-pairs cons '(1 2 3))
                '([1 . 2][2 . 3][3 . 3]))
  (check-equal? (map-slide-pairs cons '(1 2 3) #:last-val 100)
                '([1 . 2][2 . 3][3 . 100])))
```

Hopefully you can see how to extend this and make a "`map-slide-triples`" function that would be called with the previous, current, and next elements of the list.

Comment: this introduces an extra pair by duplicating the last element, which shouldn't be there. It might be better to call `(map f (drop-right xs 1) (drop xs 1))`. :)

Comment: @WillNess Actually like `map` it returns a list of the same length. Anyway although I've used this pattern in real applications (e.g. imagine calculating durations from start times, wanting +inf.0 for the last duration) of course it might not be right for other cases.